# select the max value of 2 variables

Tags: sql, firebird

I have the situation where I need to get the record of the latest date and then the max `SEQ` number. Example:

```
CLIENT_ID  STATUS  DATE        SEQ
 10          1     2019-01-03   1
 10          2     2019-01-03   2
 10          4     2019-01-02   3
 10          4     2019-01-01   2
```

Expected result

```
CLIENT_ID  STATUS  DATE        SEQ
 10          2     2019-01-03   2
```

I have tried the following code however I am having problem to filter the `SEQ` variable a to get the max value

```
SELECT client_ID,status,maxdate 
FROM sitcli 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(date) maxdate 
                FROM sitcli GROUP BY 1) a 
       ON sitcli.client_id=a.client_id AND a.maxdate=sitcli.date;
```

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `select first`:

```
select first 1 t.*
from t
order by date desc, seq desc
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, simple solution and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: if this query runs often you better create a descending index by those columns, or at least by date.